# SPFileVersionCollection - why versions are sorted in mixed order?

Tags: sharepoint, version-control, document, wss-3.0

SPFileVersionCollection and SPListItemVersionCollection versioning seems inconsistent to me. Inconsistency wouldn't be a problem to me, but sort order is.

## SPListItemVersionCollection

I can understand versioning of ListItems as they are stored in descending order:

```
SPContext.Current.ListItem.Versions.Count -> 5
SPContext.Current.ListItem.Versions[0].VersionId -> 1026 (2.2 latest version)
SPContext.Current.ListItem.Versions[1].VersionId -> 1025 (2.1)
SPContext.Current.ListItem.Versions[2].VersionId -> 1024 (2.0)
...                                [4].VersionId ->      (oldest version)
```

## SPFileVersionCollection

However I can't understand how version numbers are saved for a document library item:

```
SPContext.Current.ListItem.File.Versions.Count -> 4
SPContext.Current.ListItem.File.Versions[0].ID -> 512 (1.0 oldest one) 
SPContext.Current.ListItem.File.Versions[1].ID -> 513 (1.1)
SPContext.Current.ListItem.File.Versions[2].ID -> 1025 (2.1 latest version)
SPContext.Current.ListItem.File.Versions[3].ID -> 1024 (2.0 (EDIT: IsCurrentVersion = True))
```

They are nor in ascending order, nor descending, but something mixed.

**Is there any reason** for SharePoint team to decide to store SPFile versions like that? And do they expect that I write my own method to get latest version or is there a builtin one for that?

A note: Let me point out that SPListItem.File is not null for document library items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thought I would output some info about SPFileVersionCollection in console app and it turns out that:

- last index will hold the current (not
  drafted but published) version
  (SPFileVersion.IsCurrentVersion
  property is TRUE for this)
- 0 index holds the oldest version
- (last index - 1) has the last drafted version (for example 2.7) and (last index - 2) holds 2.6 etc.
- SPFile.Versions.Count = 0 if you just uploaded brand new document (minor version, before publishing).
- If you continue uploading new document versions and have not yet published one, then they add to SPFileVersionCollection, however none has IsCurrentVersion property set to true until you publish one.

Ahh, i had a false assumption that a last document draft version should count as the latest one. Ofcourse, the last PUBLISHED version is the latest one!

Still, beware of inconsistency.

Comment: your last two dot points seem contradictory to me - if `Count` is 0 until one is published, how can they be added to the `SPFileVersionCollection`?

Comment: @Nacht thanks for the comment. Long time since this has been tested, too lazy to go on SharePoint to make sure, but [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/24486a73-bfe0-4ed9-bf6f-32b416cbaf16/what-is-the-relation-between-spfileversions-and-splistitemversions) could shed some light: "`SPListItem.Versions.Count` is always 1 more than `SPFile.Versions.Count`. The reason is `SPFile` consider the latest version as the current version and therefore does not include this in its version collection"